# Generating expecting ) expected { and EOF found } Unity Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Syntax error on line 12 and 22 there doesn't seem to be any missing/extra brackets so it bewilders me what is causing these errors in my update function. Ideally I want the program to be able to Fire four times before having to reload for 8 seconds.

```js
#pragma strict

 var Bullet : Transform;
 var Spawn : Transform;
 var amountOfShots = 4;
 
 function Update() {
  if (Input.GetKeyDown("r") {
        Reload(); //Calls the reload function
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
        //Fires on left click
        Shoot();
        amountOfShots --;
        //Calls shoot function and removes one shot from amountOfShots
    }
}
 
function Shoot() {
    var pel = Instantiate(Bullet, Spawn.position, Spawn.rotation);
    pel.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * 6000);
    //instantiates bullet at spawn point and adds a force to propel the bullet forward
     
    if (amountOfShots <= 0) {
        Debug.Log("No ammo left in magazine");
        //Tells player if there is not enough ammo to fire
    }     
}

function OnReload()
   "setTimeout(8000, 3000)"
//Waits 8 seconds while reloading

function Reload()
{
    amountOfShots = 4;
    //resets amount of shots to 4
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou guys for fixing the issues. The code seems to work fine (no syntax errors) but the shoot function doesn't seem to be instantiating an actual bullet object. In the unity engine it just spawns a invisible Bullet(clone). Anyone have any idea why that may be? I have an actual bullet prefab in the project

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing closing bracket in your first if-statement:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("r")
```

should be

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a closing bracket on line 12 and hence the errors.

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("r"))
```

Try using an IDE that notifies the user about syntax errors. Webstorm and Brackets are good ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Functions do not follow the same procedure regarding how many instructions there are inside them as `if`, `else`, `for` and `while`.

A function must always have braces (`{` and `}`) around their bodies (even if they contain one instruction). So this:

```
function OnReload()
   "setTimeout(8000, 3000)"
```

should be this:

```
function OnReload() {
   "setTimeout(8000, 3000)"; // a ; is optional here (in this case) but it's not a good habbit to ignore them.
}
```